# Validator con petición ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, formularios, validación

Estoy validando los campos de un simple formulario que se envía al controlador mediante una petición Ajax.

El problema viene cuando imprimo por consola lo que me devuelve el controlador y resulta que siempre me devuelve todas las validaciones que tengo.
Da exactamente igual que rellene los campos o que no lo haga, por alguna razón siempre me sale por el return del error.

Mi controlador, de momento bien sencillo:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required',
        'surname' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required|numeric',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        return response()->json(['success'=>'El usuario se ha dado de alta correctamente']);
    }
    return response()->json(['error' => $validator->errors()->all()]);
}
```

Mi función Ajax con los input del formulario recogidos, tal que así:

```
var createUser = $('#addUserBtn').click(function (e) {

    var usrFormData = getFormValues();

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('#addUserBtn').html('Guardando...');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/users',
        method: 'post',
        data: usrFormData,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#addUserBtn').html('Dar de alta');
            if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                alert(data.success);
            }else{
                console.log(data.error);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Y para que no quede ninguna duda, la función JS en donde recojo los valores de los input es la siguiente:

```
function getFormValues() {
    var userData = [];
    userData['role'] = $('#sel-role').val();
    userData['coach'] = (parseInt($('#sel-role').val()) === 3 ? $('#sel-coach').val() : null);

    userData['name'] = $('#input-name').val();
    userData['surname'] = $('#input-surname').val();
    userData['phone'] = $('#input-phone').val();
    userData['email'] = $('#input-email').val();
    userData['password'] = $('#input-password').val();

    return userData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En JavaScript no puedes usar los arrays en forma de "llave => valor" es decir, no puedes hacer `userData['password']`, más bien, tendrías que crear un objeto:

```
var userData = {};
userData.role = $('#sel-role').val();
userData.coach = (parseInt($('#sel-role').val()) === 3 ? $('#sel-coach').val() : null);

userData.name = $('#input-name').val();
userData.surname = $('#input-surname').val();
userData.phone = $('#input-phone').val();
userData.email = $('#input-email').val();
userData.password = $('#input-password').val();
```

Asegúrate de que los campos en PHP después de hacer esto te estén llegando en forma de "llave => valor", haz un `dd($request->all())` y haz las modificaciones que te sean necesarias para tener ese formato antes de mandar al `Validator`.

Comment: Facepalm para mi... Gracias

Comment: @Makros Seguramente por eso te salían los errores de la validación, porque el `validator` no los encontró.

Comment: Te confirmo que funciona. Marco respuesta.